# QuTip installation error MacOsX 10.6.8 for Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install the QuTip module for python on my MacOsX 10.6.8. After downloading the .gz file and running the python setup.py install command in temrinal, I get the following error, which I do not understand (even after looking for it online):

error: Command "gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c qutip/cy/spmatfuncs.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/qutip/cy/spmatfuncs.o -w -ffast-math -O3 -march=native -mfpmath=sse" failed with exit status 1

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that the version of GCC bundled in the 10.6 developer tools is too old.  You can try installing qutip via macports

http://qutip.org/docs/3.0.1/installation.html#installation-on-mac-os-x-10-6

to see if that clears up the issue.  Also, in the future, it is best to post problems on the qutip help group board:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/qutip